# Azure SQL Azure AD Only Authentication enforcement

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-policy

I'm trying to enforce Azure AD Only Autentication on Azure SQL Server.
There is already an Built-In Policy which enforces it only for newly
created Resources but there is still the possibility after creation
to change it back to Local SQL Admin Authentication, this gap I want to close with Azure Policy.

I tried already to create a Policy with *"azureADOnlyAuthentication"* property.
but this did not work and I don't get it. Does someone have any idea?

```
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/administrators.azureADOnlyAuthentication",
            "notequals": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

> While creating a policy for Azure AD only authentication in SQL server, make sure to include below attributes:

- **The Policy Effect: DeployIfNotExist** : If condition is not met it will generate a deployment.
- **The ExistenceCondition** : If Azure SQL Server does not accept Azure AD Authentication only, then it executes a deployment.
- **Deployment** : Deployment property contains the ARM template, which is incremental. The parameter is filled with the expression *[field(‘name’)]*

Please check the ***below sample*** if helpful:

```cs
"policyRule":{
      "if":{
         "allOf":[
            {
               "field":"type",
               "equals":"Microsoft.Sql/servers"
            }
         ]
      },
      "then":{
         "effect":"deployIfNotExists",
         "details":{
            "type":"Microsoft.Sql/servers/azureADOnlyAuthentications", 
            "existenceCondition":{
               "allOf":[
                  {
                     "field":"Microsoft.Sql/servers/azureADOnlyAuthentications/azureADOnlyAuthentication",
                     "equals":true
                  }
               ]
            },
            "deployment":{
               "properties":{
                  "mode":"incremental",
                  "name":"Default",}}
```

For more in detail please **refer** below link:

[Azure SQL: Enforcing Azure AD Only Authentication - Simple Talk (red-gate.com)](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/azure-sql-enforcing-sql-authentication-type/#:%7E:text=%20Azure%20SQL:%20Enforcing%20Azure%20AD%20Only%20Authentication,change%20in%20Azure%20objects%2C%20in%20our...%20More)

Comment: Thanks for commenting :
With this solution, an admin still has the possibility for at least 30 mins
until the policy is evaluated again to disable Azure AD Auth. I was more looking for a direct deny when you try to disable the checkbox.